# WordPress Customizing Custom Post Types?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been asked to add post section to a customers WordPress website. Being fresh to wordpress i'm new on the terminology of the features of wordpress. In the menu i can see the existing two items as follows:

[image]

They've got "Posts" and "Properties" and now they want to add something the same as "Properties" but a different category called "Properties for Sale".

In WordPress are these sections referred to as "Custom Post Types"? Am I right to just install a plugin and create a new Custom Post Type?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are many plugins to create post types. Custom Post Types definitely does the job. Once you activate it you should be able to create your own post types.

If you don't want to use a plugin, there is a way to do it yourself either in functions.php or in your own plugin. For a beginner, however, using a plugin is the easiest way.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the reply. The new Post Type is going to be pretty much identical to the Properties post type. What is the easiest way to duplicate and rename the Properties Post Type?

Comment: It looks like another plugin is enabling Properties post type. This is not in Wordpress core. Why not just see what fields are in Properties post type and do the same thing in your other custom post type?

Comment: Would this be in any of the editor's php files so i could just find the underlying php code and copy/paste rename?

Answer (score 0):

There already is a plugin of some sorts installed for this.  The "Custom Post Types" menu item is not native to WP.